# Conditional probability in case of balls on succesive addition in urns

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, balls-in-bins

Four balls are placed successively in four urns, all arrangements being equally probable. Given that the first two balls are in different urns, what is the probability that one urn contains exactly three balls?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: The answer should be 1/2 according to my calculation but I cant verify it.

Comment: What does it mean "all arrangements being equally probable"? Does that mean each ball has an equal chance to be placed in each urn? Or does that mean that every arrangement of the count of balls in urns is equally probable? These are very different probabilities. In one, it is equally probable for a single urn to have all four balls as it is for every urn to have one ball. Alternately, if you were to assign a ball to an urn, and each urn is equally probable for an assignment, that is a vastly different problem.

Comment: The answer could be $\dfrac{12}{31}$ or $\dfrac{1}{8}$ depending on the meaning of "all arrangements being equally probable".

Comment: what method did you use to get 1/8

Comment: Every ball has an equal probability to wind up in any urn.

Comment: Here is how the calculation goes. Ball 1 is placed in an urn. We label that Urn A. We are told Ball 2 is placed in a different urn. We label that Urn B. Ball 3 can go into any of the four urns. There is a $\dfrac{1}{2}$ probability it will wind up in Urn A or Urn B. The last ball has an equal chance of going into any urn. The only way you wind up with three balls in the same urn is if ball 4 goes in the same urn as ball 3 and ball 3 goes in either urn A or urn B. That is: $\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{1}{8}$.

Comment: But, that may not be the correct approach. If the balls are identical, and the urns are distinct, and there is an equal probability of the arrangements of counts, the problem is still fairly straightforward, but a very different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming balls and urns are not labeled. One can trace the probability, starting with $u=4$ empty urns and probability 1 if no balls are thrown, with a state representation.  A state is a list of $i^{u_i}$ strings, meaning $u_i$ urns contain $i$ balls, $i\ge 0$. These frequqencies $u_i$ fulfil $\sum_i u_i=u$, the number of urns, and $\sum_i iu_i=b$, the number of balls. Adding a ball means that with a probability of $u_i/u$ a state can be deployed to other states when a ball is inserted into urns that already contain $u_i$ balls. The initial state is $0^2 1^2$, meaning 2 urns have no balls and 2 urns have 1 ball. The sequence of states and their probabilities (after the bar) after adding the next 0 to 4 balls are

```
# 0 balls 1 states
 0^2 1^2 | 1 1.0

# 1 balls 2 states
 0^1 1^3 | 1/2 0.5
 0^2 1^1 2^1 | 1/2 0.5

# 2 balls 4 states
 0^0 1^4 | 1/8 0.125
 0^1 1^2 2^1 | 5/8 0.625
 0^2 1^0 2^2 | 1/8 0.125
 0^2 1^1 2^0 3^1 | 1/8 0.125

# 3 balls 5 states
 0^0 1^3 2^1 | 9/32 0.28125
 0^1 1^1 2^2 | 3/8 0.375
 0^1 1^2 2^0 3^1 | 7/32 0.21875
 0^2 1^0 2^1 3^1 | 3/32 0.09375
 0^2 1^1 2^0 3^0 4^1 | 1/32 0.03125

# 4 balls 7 states
 0^0 1^2 2^2 | 39/128 0.3046875
 0^0 1^3 2^0 3^1 | 1/8 0.125
 0^1 1^0 2^3 | 3/32 0.09375
 0^1 1^1 2^1 3^1 | 11/32 0.34375
 0^1 1^2 2^0 3^0 4^1 | 29/384 0.07552083333333333
 0^2 1^0 2^0 3^2 | 3/128 0.0234375
 0^2 1^0 2^1 3^0 4^1 | 13/384 0.033854166666666664
```

That means after 2 balls are thrown, 4 in total in the urns, the probability is $1/8$ that one urn contains 3 balls.

That means after 4 balls are thrown, 6 in total in the urns, there is a probability $39/128$ that 2 urns have 1 ball and 2 urns have 2 balls, there is a probability $1/8$ that 3 urns have 1 ball and 1 urn has 3 balls, etc. So the probability that exactly 1 urn has 3 balls is $1/8+11/32=1
5/32$, the probability that 2 urns have 3 balls is $3/128$, and the probability that at least 1 urn has at least 3 balls is $1/8+11/
32+29/384+3/128+13/384=77/128$.